# When is composite of polynomial with another function also a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry

Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial and $g(x)$ be some function. Can $p(g(x))$ be a polynomial if $g$ is not a polynomial?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  You should easily be able to come up with examples, even continuous ones.

Comment: If $p(x)=x$, then the answer is not. Please clarify the problem.

Comment: If $p(x)=x^2$, and $g(x)=\sqrt x$, ....

Answer (score 2):

It seems impossible to answer this question in the level of generality you ask. In other words, I doubt there is a nice classification of functions $g(x)$ such that $p(g(x))$ is a polynomial. The answer very much depends on the nature of the polynomial $p(x)$.

As the users in the comments note:

- If $p(x)=x$, then $p(g(x)) = g(x)$ is not a polynomial if $g(x)$ is not a polynomial.
- Another example: if $p(x)=2022$ is the constant polynomial, then $p(g(x))=2022$ for any function $g(x)$.
- On the other hand, if $p(x)=x^n$ with $n\geq 2$, then we can let $g(x)=x^{1/n}$ (which is certainly not a polynomial), and yet $p(x)=(x^{1/n})^n = x$ is a polynomial. You can get more examples by considering polynomials of the form $p(x) = f(x^n)$ where $f$ is any other polynomial. Indeed, if $p(x)=f(x^n)$, then $p(g(x))=p(x^{1/n}) = f( (x^{1/n})^n) = f(x)$ is a polynomial.

On the other hand, if you know something about $g(x)$, then it would be possible to infer that $p(g(x))$ cannot be a polynomial.

- If $g(x)=e^x$, then $p(g(x))=p(e^x)$ cannot be a polynomial assuming that $p(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial.
- If $g(x)=\log(x)$, then $p(g(x))=p(\log(x))$ cannot be a polynomial assuming that $p(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial.
- If $g(x)=\operatorname{sin}(x)$, then $p(g(x))=p(\operatorname{sin}(x))$ cannot be a polynomial assuming that $p(x)$ is a non-constant polynomial.

These are based on the fact that $e^x$, $\log(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ are not algebraic functions: they are truly transcendental.

It is less clear to me what happens when $g(x)$ is a rational function $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}$ for some polynomials $f(x)$ and $h(x)$.